# How can I parse this JSON file in MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, multidimensional-array

"equipmentList":
[
{
"serial": "12I-284911-246-11",
"category": "power",
"subcategory": "VIP",
"type": "multitrak",
"nickname": "ACI",
"rails": [ "12I-284911-246-12", "12I-284911-246-13" ],
"capacitors": [],
"firingConfig": []
},
"mappedFurnaces": [
{
"serial": "12I-284911-310-11",
"id": 1
}
],
"capacitors": [
{
"capacitorId": 0,
"locationType": "capacitor",
"locationRef": 1
},
]

Comment: [ask], https://json2csharp.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

....
var json=" ... your json";
  
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json); 

    foreach (var furnace in data.EquipmentList[0].MappedFurnaces)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Furnace:  serial = {furnace.Serial}  id = {furnace.Id}");

    }
    foreach (var capactor in data.EquipmentList[0].Capacitors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Capacitor:  id = {capactor.CapacitorId}  locationType = {capactor.LocationType}");
    }
```

classes

```
    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("equipmentList")]
        public List<EquipmentList> EquipmentList { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class EquipmentList
    {
        [JsonProperty("serial")]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("subcategory")]
        public string Subcategory { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nickname")]
        public string Nickname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rails")]
        public List<string> Rails { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("capacitors")]
        public List<Capacitor> Capacitors { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("firingConfig")]
        public List<object> FiringConfig { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mappedFurnaces")]
        public List<MappedFurnace> MappedFurnaces { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Capacitor
    {
        [JsonProperty("capacitorId")]
        public long CapacitorId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationType")]
        public string LocationType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationRef")]
        public long LocationRef { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MappedFurnace
    {
        [JsonProperty("serial")]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }
```

after fixing your json

```
{
    "equipmentList": [{
        "serial": "12I-284911-246-11",
        "category": "power",
        "subcategory": "VIP",
        "type": "multitrak",
        "nickname": "ACI",
        "rails": ["12I-284911-246-12", "12I-284911-246-13"],
        "capacitors": [],
        "firingConfig": [],
        "mappedFurnaces": [{
            "serial": "12I-284911-310-11",
            "id": 1
        }],
        "capacitors": [{
            "capacitorId": 0,
            "locationType": "capacitor",
            "locationRef": 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: thank you. This is very helpful. Also, I'm trying to display the values using ASP.net MVC. I managed to display the values of the objects from HTML but I couldn't display the objects under mappedFurnaces and capacitors. Do you know how to resolve the issue? Thank you so much.

Comment: @iowa I updated my answer with examples how to use. Try again and let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much.... It worked. I really appreciate the help sir!!!